# Similar images training set generator

Tags: opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, deep-learning, generator

I want to train my machine learning (Watson visual recognition) to detect sun doodle (black and white).
The problem is that I have to train at least 700 images but I have just something like 30.

[image: A screen-shot of my gallery:]

I thought about a generator that takes my images and changes them and creates a lot of similar images using pixel games. 
Do you know a generator like this? Or do you have a good idea for me?

Thanks.

Comment: I know this is not the kind of answer you are looking for, but doodling a sun takes around 2-3 seconds. This means, that you can doodle 600 suns in around 1200-1800 seconds, 20-30 min. This is not a generic solution of course, but *proper* data is the most important part of any ML. Don't look for shortcuts if all you need is 30 mins of work.

Comment: @lejlot you should post an answer with your comment.

Comment: supporting @lejlot "proper data is the most important part of any ML" ask help from people around you. to get different samples

Comment: You don't need 700 images. The classifier will work with 50 images.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand how you only got 30 images while all your images come from a dataset (namely the Google quickdraw-dataset) that contains 129,631 sun drawings! The easiest way to collect more sun images is probably to download the entire dataset which is available  [here](https://quickdraw.withgoogle.com/data/sun).

[image]